# "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument" Error Keeps coming

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been trying to ask PowerShell to move certain files using a CSV file to indicate where, what needs to be moved to.

Here is my script:

```
import-csv sample1.csv  | foreach { copy-item $_.source\$_.file $_.destination\$_.file}
```

Here is the csv its meant to get the information from.
[image of the CSV of files i need to move.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4o0I.jpg)

Please, if anyone can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

What's the full error? Assume it doesn't like the fact you're not using quotes:

```
Import-Csv sample1.csv  |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path "$_.source\$_.file" -Destination "$_.destination\$_.file"
    }
```